# Pandas columns variable length string slicing based on conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame `df` like this,

```
    A           length
0   648702831   9
1    26533315   8
2         366   3
3   354701058   9
4    25708239   8
5       70554   5
6     1574512   7
7        3975   4
```

Now, I want to create a column  based on some conditions like this,

```
if ['length] == 9 or ['length] == 5:
   then ['new_col'] = First 5 Characters of ['A']

else if ['length] == 8 or ['length] == 4:
   then ['new_col'] = "0" & First 4 Characters of ['A']

else if ['length] == 7 or ['length] == 3:
   then ['new_col'] = "00" & First 3 Characters of ['A']

else 
   ['new_col'] = ['A']
```

For above conditions, I created the following logic to check, (For a file with 10,000 rows, it takes a lot of time)

```
for i in df['length']:

    if i == 9 or i == 5:
        df['new_col'] = df['A'].astype(str).str[:5]
    elif i == 8 or i == 4:
        df['new_col'] = "0" + df['A'].astype(str).str[:4]

    elif i == 7 or i == 3:
        df['new_col'] = "00" + df['A'].astype(str).str[:3]

    else:
        df['new_col'] = df['A']
```

I get the following output,

```
    A          length   new_col
0   648702831   9      06487
1    26533315   8      02653
2         366   3      0366
3   354701058   9      03547
4     5708239   8      05708
5       70554   5      07055
6      1574512  7      01574
7         3975  4      03975
```

This is not I want and it seems to be working only for second condition that adds "0" in front when the length is 8 or 4.

I need my output like this,

```
   A           length   new_col
0   648702831   9       64870
1    26533315   8       02653
2         366   3       00366
3   354701058   9       35470
4     5708239   8       05708
5       70554   5       70554
6      1574512  7       00157
7         3975  4       03975
```

How can I achieve this and also if there is a `pandas` way that can take less time, that would be great. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use string slicing with `zfill`. For speed, use a list comprehension.

```
m = {1: 5, 0: 4, 3: 3}
df['new_col'] = [
    x[:m.get(y % 4, 4)].zfill(5) for x, y in zip(df['A'].astype(str), df['length'])]

df
           A  length new_col
0  648702831       9   64870
1   26533315       8   02653
2        366       3   00366
3  354701058       9   35470
4   25708239       8   02570
5      70554       5   70554
6    1574512       7   00157
7       3975       4   03975
```

---

To handle the default case, we can implement a little extra checking when calling `zfill`:

```
df = df.append({'A' : 50, 'length': 2}, ignore_index=True)
```

```
m = {1: 5, 0: 4, 3: 3}

df['new_col'] = [
    x[:m.get(y % 4, 4)].zfill(5 if y % 4 in m else 0) 
    for x, y in zip(df['A'].astype(str), df['length'])
]

df
           A  length new_col
0  648702831       9   64870
1   26533315       8   02653
2        366       3   00366
3  354701058       9   35470
4   25708239       8   02570
5      70554       5   70554
6    1574512       7   00157
7       3975       4   03975
8         50       2      50   # Default case.
```

Comment: I am getting a `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'length'` that for my orginal dataframe. For the my test case with smaller data frame this is working. I googled it, and found I can use `df[column].length`. But no luck yet! Any idea why?

Comment: @user9431057 Can you tell me the output of `df.columns`?

Comment: this is what I get: `Index(['A', 'length', 'new_col'], dtype='object')`

Comment: @user9431057 I've edited. What happens if you try to access using `df['length']`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a list comprehension with a dictionary. This is perfectly acceptable considering Pandas `str` methods are not vectorised.

```
d = {5: 5, 9: 5, 8: 4, 4: 4, 3: 3, 7: 3}

zipper = zip(df['A'].astype(str), df['length'])

df['new_col'] = [A[:d[L]].zfill(5) if L in d else A for A, L in zipper]

print(df)

           A  length new_col
0  648702831       9   64870
1   26533315       8   02653
2        366       3   00366
3  354701058       9   35470
4   25708239       8   02570
5      70554       5   70554
6    1574512       7   00157
7       3975       4   03975
8         12       2      12
```

Answer (score 3):

Fix your code

```
df['new_col']=''
for i,j in zip(df['length'],df.index):

    df.A = df.A.astype(str)
    if i == 9 or i == 5:
        df.loc[j,'new_col'] =  df.loc[j,'A'][:5]
    elif i == 8 or i == 4:
        df.loc[j, 'new_col'] = "0" + df.loc[j,'A'][:4]

    elif i == 7 or i == 3:
        df.loc[j, 'new_col'] = "00" + df.loc[j,'A'][:3]

    else:
        df.loc[j, 'new_col']= df.loc[j,'A']


df
Out[52]: 
           A  length new_col
0  648702831       9   64870
1   26533315       8   02653
2        366       3   00366
3  354701058       9   35470
4   25708239       8   02570
5      70554       5   70554
6    1574512       7   00157
7       3975       4   03975
```

Comment: thanks for the post. Why did we `zip` here? Is to make it faster (the way I have?)?

Comment: @user9431057 the way you have change the whole value for each time , zip here is using the index adding each value within one loop , rather than change the whole columns, why you get your "wrong" output --- you overwrite whole column each time , so the final output of new-column equal to `"0" + df['A'].astype(str).str[:4]`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a lambda function:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[298347,9287384, 983, 9283, 894, 1]})
df['new_col'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: '{0:0>8}'.format(x))

         A      Col1
0   298347  00298347
1  9287384  09287384
2      983  00000983
3     9283  00009283
4      894  00000894
5        1  00000001
```

Comment: thanks for the post, but I need something like I posted above. A need to be able to add one zero or two "`00`"'s based on the condition.